# Matlab: memory leak in table.subsref() on 2014b pre-release (or 2014a)?

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks

Working on R2014b_Prerelease, Windows7x64, 8gb RAM

The following lines of code (the last one) cause a memory leak on my system and force me to restart the pc:

```
N   = 2e7;
tb  = table(rand(N,1),'VariableNames',{'A'});
pos = randperm(N)';
tb  = tb(pos, 'A');
```

Can anybody else **reproduce** the same behaviour? You might need to run the code a few times before it leaks.

Basically, a little after completing the last line, the memory shoots up to ~8gb. However, I can't post any screenshot (pc hangs).

Comment: can't reproduce the memory leak on R2014a (Win8.1, 8GB RAM); once allocated, the memory remains relatively constant no matter how many times the code is re-run.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Tried 10x in both R2014b prerelease (Win 7, 24GB RAM) and R2013b (Win 7, 8GB RAM).

Comment: @excaza What if you try to scale the problem up in your 24gb rig by radically incrementing `N`?

Comment: @Amro I started a new session, cleared all, then had to try 15x before I could observe the behaviour. Also, to re-run the code, I only execute the last two lines, 5 seconds apart.